# Correct way to locate text document for windows form application executable

Tags: c#, winforms, file, executable

what is a correct way to save text document for windows form application executable file for other user. Now I got it in *D:\Pro\bin\Debug* folder usually

```
"doc.txt";
```

maybe better go this way:

```
@"c:\temp\doc.txt";
```

or this:

```
"C:\ProgramData\doc\doc.text";
```

or maybe better some other way?

1. Document must be available for each separate user on his local computer, each user has his own document
2. the program is constantly makes requests to this document, but it must be removed with uninstalling
3. Document don't need to be in a visible location

Comment: Use `%ProgramData%\YourAppName\doc.txt`

Comment: **You should never use hard coded path. This is a very bad habit.** You don't know folder that exists on user computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving the file to the exeutable path folder works, since another user will need to have acces to that path to be able to execute the program in the first place.

Alternatives would be:

`C:\Users\Public\AppData\Roaming\AppFolder`
or `%ProgramData%`.

Comment: and what is wrong with  `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp` and `%AppData%\AppFolder`?

Comment: I removed that because that paths belong to the user, so other users won't have access to them.

Comment: @viktor80 Any hard-coded path is bad... You don't know if %username% is under drive `c:\Users`. You should always use functions to get predefined path!

Comment: If the document is for a single user and should be visible, then it should be under user documents.

Answer (score 1):

You question is incomplete because you don't say if the document should be per user or for all users. Also you don't say if it is a temporary document. And you don't indicate if you prefer the document to be in a visible location.

Usually, documents should be stored under user document folder.

By the way, you should always use always use a function to get the base folder [SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx). Typically, for user documents, you would specify `MyDocuments`. And usually, an application that create many files might want to create its own sub-folder (use `Path.Combine` for that purpose).

Be aware that if you want to share data with many users, you might have to use a folder common to all user and maybe even adjust security.

For sure, any way you have shown in your question **are very bad**. Specified hard coded folder might not exist. Any programmer should know that folder depends on which drive Windows is installed, OS language and version and some of those folders can be customized by the user...

Comment: ok thank you question edited

Comment: Well, usually user documents are not removed when the program is uninstalled. In fact, if the application is installed for all users, then it probably won't be possible to remove documents of other users because you won't have access to their documents. And for the current user, you would probably have to write custom actions to do that. In practice, I really doubt that you want to go there...
Well, for "hidden" application data, you have other special folders. There are multiple options depending on if the data is roaming or not (so that in enterprise you can have the data following you)